# Merge folders with similar names in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, file-management, merge

For every folder named "abc & xyz", I have a folder named xyz & abc. I would like to merge folder "abc & xyx" with folder named "xyz & abc". What is the best way to do this? I have 1000s of such folders so I am looking for an automated way of doing this.

Comment: Open both folders.  Create a new folder.  Drag and drop the contents of both folders into the new folder.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest?
Dragging and dropping one into the other.

You could also open one file <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to select all.  Then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> into the one you want to merge contents into.

Then delete the remaining empty folder.